# PHP function fails in second instance

Tags: php, html, arrays, function

I have a function as follows which outputs options into a dropdown form in a hierarchical (indented) fashion:

```
<?php
function printTerms($terms, $item, $parent = 0, $deep = 0, $selected=''){
    if(count($terms[$parent]) > 0){
        $indent = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < $deep; $i++){
            $indent .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }

        foreach($terms[$parent] as $key => $term){
            if(count($terms[$term->term_id]) > 0){
                if($deep == 0){
 //                 echo "<optgroup label='".$term->name."'></optgroup>";                     <- Makes top level parents optgroups. 
                    echo "<option class='toplevel' value='".$term->name."' ".$selected.">".$term->name."</option>";   //     <- Makes top level parents options
_________________________________________________________________________
                } else {
                    echo "<option class='child".$deep."' value='".$term->name."' ".$selected.">".$indent.$term->name."</option>";  // <- Outputs children that are also parents
                }

                printTerms($terms, $term->term_id, ($deep+1));

            } else {
                if ($item == '1x per person' && $term->slug == 'once'){ 
                    $selected = 'selected';
                }
                echo "<option class='solo' value='".$term->name."' ".$selected.">".$indent.$term->name."</option>";   // <- outputs bottom level children and solos.
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The above function works when coupled with this code which places the form in HTML (let's call this CASE 1):

```
<form>
       <div id="frequency" class="form">
            Frequency: <?php echo $item[2]; ?>
            <?php
             $terms = array();         
                foreach($frequencies as $key => $term){
                    $terms[$term->parent][$term->term_id] = $term;
                }
            ?>    
            <select name="frequencies">
                <option value="empty"></option>
                <?php printTerms($terms, $item[2]); ?>
            </select>
        </div>
</form>
```

The above function DOES NOT WORK when coupled with this code which places a multi-select form in HTML (CASE 2):

```
<form>
       <div id="regions" class="form">
            <?php
             $terms = array();              
                foreach($regions as $key => $term){
                    $terms[$term->parent][$term->term_id] = $term;
                }
            ?>    
            <select name="regions">
    <!--        <option value="empty"></option>         -->
                <?php printTerms($terms, $item[6]); ?>
            </select>
        </div>
</form>
```

$frequencies is an object array and contains:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 435 [name] => Twice [slug] => twice [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 435 [taxonomy] => frequency [description] => Twice the fun. [parent] => 0 [count] => 89 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 449 [name] => Thrice [slug] => thrice [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 449 [taxonomy] => frequency [description] => Thrice rhymes with mice. [parent] => 0 [count] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 458 [name] => Once [slug] => once [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 460 [taxonomy] => frequency [description] => Once a day keeps doctor away. [parent] => 0 [count] => 4 ) )
```

$regions is an object array and contains:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 436 [name] => Canada [slug] => canada [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 436 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 548 [count] => 33 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 439 [name] => United States of America [slug] => united-states-of-america [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 439 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 548 [count] => 59 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 452 [name] => Quebec [slug] => quebec [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 452 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 436 [count] => 4 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 28 [name] => Ontario [slug] => ontario [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 453 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 436 [count] => 2 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 453 [name] => New Brunswick [slug] => new-brunswick [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 454 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 436 [count] => 3 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 454 [name] => Nova Scotia [slug] => nova-scotia [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 455 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 436 [count] => 3 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 455 [name] => Prince Edward Island [slug] => prince-edward-island [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 456 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 436 [count] => 3 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 456 [name] => Newfoundland [slug] => newfoundland [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 457 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 436 [count] => 3 ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 464 [name] => Alberta [slug] => alberta [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 466 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 436 [count] => 1 ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 465 [name] => Saskatchewan [slug] => saskatchewan [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 467 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 436 [count] => 1 ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 466 [name] => Manitoba [slug] => manitoba [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 468 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 436 [count] => 1 ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 467 [name] => British Columbia [slug] => british-columbia [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 469 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 436 [count] => 1 ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 468 [name] => Yukon [slug] => yukon [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 470 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 436 [count] => 1 ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 469 [name] => Northwest Territories [slug] => northwest-territories [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 471 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 436 [count] => 1 ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 470 [name] => Nunavut [slug] => nunavut [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 472 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 436 [count] => 1 ) [15] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 548 [name] => World Wide [slug] => world-wide [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 551 [taxonomy] => regions [parent] => 0 [count] => 20 ) )
```

So what's different? 
In CASE 1, we have a simple dropdown menu that is calling printTerms($terms, $item[2]) - WORKS: Outputs all parents and their children with indents.

In CASE 2, we have a simple dropdown menu that is calling printTerms($terms, $item[6]) - DOESN'T WORK: Outputs only top level parents, ignores all children.

This is what $item[6] contains compared to $item[2]:

```
$item[2] contains '1x per rotation'
$item[6] contains 'Enter only if U.S. 18+'
```

Other than the above, both CASE 1 and CASE 2 are identical, so how do I fix my problem?

UPDATE: Inserted dotted lines in my function code to demonstrate that everything above the line works in CASE 2 but nothing below the line does. For CASE 1, everything above and below the line works as expected.

UPDATE x2: The function when used with CASE 2 doesn't appear to be looping. HOWEVER, if I remove $item entirely  from all the functions' code, it works perfectly fine. SOMETHING about $item is preventing my function from looping. The question is why?

Comment: What do `$frequencies` and `$regions` contain?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was simple:

```
<?php printTerms($terms, 0, 0, 0, $item[2]); ?>
```